# Excel: Conditional Formatting by Row Header and not Row Number

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I need to highlight values between 1 and 30 across 150 tabs in a specific row. This row fluctuates between row 6, row 7, row 8 and row 9 between each tab, so I am trying to do this by the row header named TOTAL. Is this possible?

Comment: Which part of that is giving you problems?

Comment: Most importantly doing it across all 150 tabs at once. I can just highlight rows 6-9 and do the conditional formatting, it will just highlight some information I don't want to be highlighted, which isn't the worst thing (because the TOTAL row ends up in different rows in some of the tabs because of formatting (between 6 - 9). IF I can also do conditional formatting by row HEADER that would be great.

Comment: It would help if you could explain exactly how the row header fits in to your task.

Comment: It is possible to do this, please show the code you are trying to use...

Comment: Any number under 30 I need to highlight red in the TOTAL Column. I just need to do a conditional format for rows 6-9 (any value between 1.1 and 30 = shaded red). I did that, but don't know how to do it across multiple worksheets. If i Could only restrict it to which of the rows contain the header TOTAL, that would be great, but its not essential.

Comment: @user3638007 With 150 worksheets, I suggest you use VBA.  You can develop the code for doing the conditional format using the macro recorder; then it's just a matter of cycling through each worksheet; "find" Total (probably only have to check A6:A9 on each sheet) and apply the conditional format operation you recorded to the entire row.  There's no easy way to do it manually.

Comment: In excel 2003 you can just select all worksheets at once and apply conditional formatting for row 6 on all worksheets. Thats really all i want to do, but you cant do that on 2007...

Comment: @user3638007  That is different from your question.  I thought you only wanted to CF the rows that had Total.  See an answer

Comment: I did but Ive been trying to figure this out for two days and I can't seem to get an answer, If that is actually possible I would like to do that, but just formatting multiple rows is a fall back.

Comment: @user3638007 In one of my comments I already gave you an answer. It involved VBA and I gave you some ideas as to how to approach the problem. But I don't see where you have supplied any of the VBA code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has posted in comments that he now only wants to apply the conditional formatting to row 6 in all of the worksheets, and not the various rows that might contain the word TOTAL.  To do this, in Excel 2007

```
Apply the desired conditional formatting to Row 6 on a single sheet.
Select the entire Row 
Select the Format Painter 
Navigate to the next sheet
Select all of the sheets you wish to CF Row 6
Select Row 6 (click on the 6 with the Format Painter)
```

While you cannot CF multiple sheets at the same time in Excel 2007, you can CF a single sheet, and then copy that format to **multiple sheets simultaneously**.

**EDIT:** I see you have recorded a macro to produce the conditional formatting and pasted it into one of your comments.

The next step is to modify it to find the word Total in one of the rows 6:8, and apply the formatting only to that row.

Here is a modification of what you posted, that should do that for every sheet.  I also cleaned up the code the macro recorder produced.  Note that the macro assumes that the Row header is always in the first column (column A).  It cycles through each worksheet and applies the formatting to the relevant row in that range.

In addition, and this may or may not be desired, the macro removes conditional formatting from other cells in those rows.

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set R = WS.Rows("6:8")
        R.FormatConditions.Delete  'get rid of old formatconditions
    With R.Columns(1)
        Set C = .Find(what:="TOTAL", LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        With C.EntireRow
            .FormatConditions.Add _
                Type:=xlCellValue, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, _
                Formula1:="=1.0000001", _
                Formula2:="=30"
            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 13551615
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With
    End If
Next WS
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
The OP now wants a range of 0 to 30, but to exclude empty cells.  So we will alter the CF to be a formula (expression) that will also test that there is a number in the cell:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set R = WS.Rows("6:8")
        R.FormatConditions.Delete  'get rid of old formatconditions
    With R.Columns(1)
        Set C = .Find(what:="TOTAL", LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        With C.EntireRow
            .FormatConditions.Add _
                Type:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="=and(isnumber(" & C.Address(True, False) & "), " & _
                    C.Address(True, False) & ">=0, " & _
                    C.Address(True, False) & "<=30)"
            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 13551615
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next WS
End Sub
```

Comment: I still have to do this worksheet by worksheet though, there is no way around that?

Comment: @user3638007 Without using VBA, you cannot format worksheets without selecting them. Do you know how to select more than one sheet at a time?  You select the first sheet in a range; hold down the shift key; then select the last sheet in the range.  All of the sheets from first to last will be selected.

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'
    Rows("6:8").Select
    Range("B6").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=1.0000001", Formula2:="=30"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub

Comment: is there way I can change Rows("6:8") to something like, Rows("TOTAL"header=true)

Comment: Its oddly only work for a few worksheets, but that is basically it.

Comment: @user3638007 What does it do when it **doesn't work?**  What is different about the worksheets that it doesn't work on?

Comment: Nevermind. It's basically perfect. I had the range at 1.1-30, but I've changed it to 0-30 (because I do want to include zeros). Everything works perfectly, however, after the data, all blank spaces after in the TOTAL row are highlighted. Anyway around that? Thank you so much as well.

Comment: I just want to exclude blank cells from conditional formatting, because it highlighting every blank cell. (range change to 0 to 30)

Comment: @user3638007 Well since the value of a blank cell is zero, it's doing what you tell it to do.  If you want to ensure that there is a number entry in there, then you'll have to use a formula instead of the "between" test.  See my answer for a possible solution.